# pyocd Debugging with NXP KW41Z development board

Tags: python, debugging, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to run sample projects of zephyr RTOS on NXP KW41Z. I manage to build the project but I can't flash it to the board. According to the manual of zephyr([manual ref](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/boards/arm/frdm_kw41z/doc/index.html)), I must use Pyocd to flash the elf file to the board. I installed pyocd through pip but when I try start pyocd gdbserver but I get stuck in this state:

[image]

I also try `pyocd list` but no available devices are found.

any suggestions?